# Static IP address for IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub

For the scenario where a firewall/proxy doesn't support IoT Hub's FQDN.

The recommended approach is to script the updating of the firewall's whitelist - not going to happen in our case.

My plan B is to introduce a "gateway" on the IoT Hub side to provide a static IP address, and forward traffic to IoT Hub. I can see a few azure appliances which might serve here:

- Azure Application Gateway
- Azure Firewall
- Azure Load Balancer
- Proxy Server on VM

Has somebody been through this? What was your experience, and where did you land?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something like this by building an HA proxy solution (based on Squid proxy) on a VM Scale Set with a Load Balancer in front. You can find the full solution here: https://github.com/sebader/azure-samples-collection/tree/master/VmssProxySolution

This one uses an internal LB (private IP) but you can also easily modify this to expose a static, public IP.